# How to run PowerShell inside an SSH session (with Win32-OpenSSH on Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, openssh

I have set up [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) on Windows 10. I can establish an SSH session and run the CLI commands.

When I execute PowerShell, however, it does not run. I suspect it might try to open a separate window. The transcript is as follows:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14366]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\techraf>powershell

C:\Users\techraf>echo %errorlevel%
-1073741502

C:\Users\techraf>
```

Is there anything I can/should do to make it work inside the SSH session?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Thanks once again for making me dig into the problem. Seemingly it was a bug in one of the Insider Preview versions, which at the time I needed access to. With a new version, PowerShell runs with no problems, as I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly it is a bug in one of the Windows 10 Insider Preview versions. The newer one runs PowerShell with no problem:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

techraf@Win10 C:\Users\techraf>powershell
powershell
          Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


PS C:\Users\techraf>
```